# AngularJS обращение к директиве ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пользуясь AngularJS и вывожу элементы массива в список вот таким образом:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
        <p>{{phone.name}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Как мне обратится к конкретному элементу при нажатии на него?**

сменить стиль например или поместить в переменную